# JQuery Vadliation for Video Upload Maximum 3Minute

Tags: jquery, validation, video

i m looking a code for validation 3minutes video while uploading. i.e i want to check when click on submit button whether uploaded video is 3minutes video or small or large than that using jquery..

Comment: you have to upload the video first before using any file reader to get the video length.

Answer (score 0):

You can get video duration with ffmpeg or getID3

Example:

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filename);
echo("Duration: ".$file['playtime_string'].
" / Dimensions: ".$file['video']['resolution_x']." wide by ".$file['video']['resolution_y']." tall".
" / Filesize: ".$file['filesize']." bytes<br />");
```

for more information:
See: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Comment: it will check before uploading video or after video uploading?

Comment: the only way to get video duration is after uploading, you can not do it before

Comment: Thanks for your info.. i used this same code that you gave but i m not sure using jqeury... now i follow you